# Extracting URL parameters with AngularJS using hashbang method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-parameters

Currently, I am using AngularJS html4mode to extract URL parameters. I would like to change to using hashbang method because my routing got screwed up after enabling html4mode.

For extracting URL parameters using html4mode, the URL is `http://127.0.0.1/webroot/start.html?Venue=XXX`

The configuration code for $locationProvider is as follows;

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);  //configure $location
```

Inside the controller;

```
var url_param = ($location.search()).Venue;
```

I failed when I tried to convert to hashbang. I am at a loss now

To convert to hashbang, how would the URL look like and what changes need to be made to the controller and configuration of $locationProvider?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you turn off html5mode the URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/webroot/start.html?Venue=XXX
```

becomes

```
http://127.0.0.1/webroot/start.html#/?Venue=XXX
```

if you want use hashbang URL (for SEO, Facebook or whatever) you should add the "!" prefix to your URL, with:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');
```

And your URL becomes:

```
http://127.0.0.1/webroot/start.html#!/?Venue=XXX
```

the search method of $location should work, following the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location#search)

Move from html5Mode to hashbang (or vice versa) needs you to refactor the links in your app.
To avoid this kind of situation I prefer using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and modify links in terms of state transition (i.e. using [ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive%3aui-sref)). In this way, it's ui-router that modify the URL with or without the hash for you

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made some slight modification to get the right answer which I have tested and confirmed on my side. See the edited URL.